# Keypresses/Updates not being called properly?

Tags: javascript, three.js, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe

I am attempting to make a game in Javascript, but currently I've reached a standstill. I am trying to detect keypresses and check if they are down constantly to move the character. This is the code I am using:

```
var THREE;
var keys;
var update;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var player_fov = 45;
var player_aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var player_near = 0.1;
var player_far = 10000;
var player_camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(player_fov, player_aspect, player_near, player_far);
var player_material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color: 0xd0bd4b});
var player_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1,1);
var player = new THREE.Mesh(player_geometry, player_material);


function INIT()
{
    scene.add(player);
    player_camera.position.z = 5;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        keys.keys = (keys.keys || []);
        keys.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e){
        keys.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(INIT);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene, player_camera);
    if(keys.keys && keys.keys[87]) //w
    {
        player.position.y += 1;
    }
    if(keys.keys && keys.keys[65]) //a
    {
        player.position.x -= 1;
    }
    if(keys.keys && keys.keys[83]) //s
    {
        player.position.y -= 1;
    }
    if(keys.keys && keys.keys[68]) //d
    {
        player.position.x += 1;
    }
}
```

This is not working when I press whatever keys. Should be a fairly easy error to spot for a better programmer. Is it a bad understanding of eventListeners or requestAnimationFrame? If it is, let me know how I can fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things to improve in you code:

1. You are never calling the INIT() function, so that code is never run.
2. You should not use `requestAnimationFrame` in the INIT function. There is a lot of code there that does not have to be run every frame.
3. Create a `function render(){...}` that is called at the end of INIT or directly after you call INIT. THe render function should have the `requestAnimationFrame(render)`
4. Use a javascript Object instead of array for the keys.

These things are the most urgent i believe. Below is a working example.

```js
var keys = {};
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var player_fov = 45;
var player_aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var player_near = 0.1;
var player_far = 10000;
var player_camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(player_fov, player_aspect, player_near, player_far);
var player_material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color: 0xd0bd4b});
var player_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1,1);
var player = new THREE.Mesh(player_geometry, player_material);

INIT();

function INIT()
{
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    keys = (keys || {});
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  });

  document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  });
  
    scene.add(player);
    player_camera.position.z = 5;
  
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
   render();
}


function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    if(keys && keys[87]) //w
    {
      player.position.y += 0.2;
    }
    if(keys && keys[65]) //a
    {
      player.position.x -= 0.2;
    }
    if(keys && keys[83]) //s
    {
      player.position.y -= 0.2;
    }
    if(keys && keys[68]) //d
    {
      player.position.x += 0.2;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, player_camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r75/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! For starters, INIT() is called in my <body onload> tag in my HTML file, but I didn't make that evident, so no error on your part there. Second, thanks for clarifying that my requestAnimationFrame was called improperly. I will keep your answer in mind when adding future items to the game. Thanks for the advice